# Having issues using span and colors in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a green dot on a chat window, just like facebook does. 
[image]

My section of the html that refers to my problem looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<span class="green"> </span> Chat (32)
</div>
```

My CSS code looks like this:

```
 .green {
  color: green;
}
```

Every other element in my CSS works fine, so it's not a reference issue. Only this one. the green dot is not being generated.

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I just edited my question with that info.

Comment: `background-color`, not `color`; when CSS doesn't work it's worth looking up what the property you've tried to style actually does.

Comment: Still does not work...thank you for the tip though

Comment: Take a look at my snippet below, that will give you the round green dot you seek. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the color to green implies that there is some text/character in that span to be colored (*[unicode character •](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) should do*).

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
<span class="green">•</span> Chat (32)
</div>
```

---

Alternatively (*if cannot change the html*) you might want to use `background-color` and make the element round

```css
.green {
  display:inline-block;
  width:0.5em;
  height:0.5em;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
<span class="green"> </span> Chat (32)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a `span` is an inline element, it's sized by its content.

Give the span `display inline-block` so it responds to having a size set, a `padding` to give it a size, a `border-radius` to make it round and use `background`, not `color`, to give it a color.

```css
.green {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 6px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <span class="green"> </span> Chat (32)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a couple of things like a width/height, background-color, and border-radius.

Also, consider naming your css classes by what they represent, not how they end up looking.

```css
.status {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.online {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <span class="status online"> </span> Chat (32)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```css
.green {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="green"></div> Chat (32)
</div>
```

Then you can change that green element to another color when Offline.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.greenDot{
    background: #42b72a;
    border-radius: 69%;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0 3px 1px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="greenDot"></span>Chat
```

```css
    .greenDot{
        background: #42b72a;
        border-radius: 69%;
        height: 6px;
        margin: 0 3px 1px 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 6px;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="greenDot"></span>Chat
```